# Añadir código en función.php para validar d.n.i con acf

Tags: funciones

Necesito validar un campo de texto de acf con el d.n.i, tengo la función que sirve, pero fallo al ponerla en función.php para con los valores de acf, no se que estoy haciendo mal, este es mi código:

```
add_action('acf/render_field_settings/type=textarea', 'validar_dni');
function validar_dni($dni){
 $letra = substr($dni, -1);
    $numeros = substr($dni, 0, -1);
    if ( substr("TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE", $numeros%23, 1) == $letra && strlen($letra) == 1 && strlen ($numeros) == 8 ){
        echo 'valido';
    }else{
        echo 'no valido';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me he encontrado con esta misma necesidad y he completado el código. Esto funciona en un formulario de registro con campos ACF. Mi campo, en este caso, se llama "documento".

```
function validarDNI($dni){
$letra = substr($dni, -1);
$numeros = substr($dni, 0, -1);
if ( substr("TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE", $numeros%23, 1) == $letra && strlen($letra) == 1 && strlen ($numeros) == 8 ){
    // DNI Válido
    return true;
} else {
    // DNI no válido
    return false;   
    }
}

function my_acf_validate_value( $valid, $value, $field, $input_name ) {

    $valid =  validarDNI($value);
    if( $valid !== true ) {
        return __( 'DNI / NIF incorrecto');
    }
return $valid;
}
```